# Material with half-life that is being added to periodically

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

I am having trouble calculating this problem:

$X$ amount of material with $Y$ half-life is administered on a patient.

When an interval of time  $=A$  elapses, ( as a given fraction of half-life)  an amount of medicine $=B$is given periodically.

How do I plot the current amount of material/medicine available against time axis?

I believe that some form of recursion is needed, but I can't wrap my head about the formula...
Thank you.

Comment: Do you start from $0$, or are you interested in the steady-state behavior that the process converges towards?

Comment: I am mostly interested in the steady-state behavior that the process converges towards coupled with how long does it take to reach that state, IF possible easily then with start from 0, but that is secondary.

Answer (score 2):

No matter how much material is there immediately if you have "topped up", after $A$ time passes a *fixed* fraction of the material will have decayed. If $A$ is measured in half-lifes, the relation is
$$ (\text{amount at time }t+A) = 2^{-A}(\text{amount at time }t) $$
when there are no toppings-up in between.

Thus if $X_n$ is the amount immediately after topping up for the $n$th time, we have the recurrence
$$ X_{n+1} = 2^{-A}X_n + B $$

For the steady state, set $X_{n+1}=X_n$ and solve, giving $X=\frac{B}{1-2^{-A}}$.

Starting from $0$, the growth pattern is that the *difference* between $X_n$ and the steady-state $X$ decreases by a factor of $2^{-X}$ for each iteration.